# rails redirect_to doesn't load the javascript under assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

if my controller is page_controller.rb and the associated javascript file under assets is page.js then nothing in the page.js will reload when I use re_direct

I tried the following

```
redirect_to page_path, data: { no_turbolink: true }
```

but it didn't work, although it works fine with link_to

```
link_to 'page title', page_link, data: { no_turbolink: true }
```

any idea?

Edit:

I have in the following in my `index.html.haml`:

```
%li
  = link_to status, page_status_path({param1: hello, param2: hello2})
```

and in my controller I have:

```
def index
  ....
end

def status
  redirect_to index_path, data: { no_turbolink: true }
end
```

Now I know that the turbo link path doesn't make sense but how to load the javascript when I redirect back to index?

Comment: What are you trying to do? tubolinks have nothing to do with your controller, it's all on the client side.

Comment: the javascript won't load with turbo-links

Comment: What javascript? Can you update the question with more details?

Comment: if my controller is page_controller.rb and the associated javascript file under assets is page.js then nothing in the page.js will reload with turbo_links by default. in my views I always pass the parameter data: {no_turbolinl: true}

Comment: Turbolinks does not work with redirections, it's actually an attribute to HTML markups (meaning something big, of course). So, you must supply it where you call the link that routes to your controller action where the redirect occurs. In other very generic words, where the "click" occurs.

Comment: Turbolinks doesn't load some js files as you browse page to page (It's because the nodes on which you bind events no longer exist.), but this gem solves that problem. `gem "jquery-turbolinks"`

Comment: jquery-turbolinks solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turbolinks doesn't load some js files as you browse page to page (It's because the nodes on which you bind events no longer exist.), but this gem solves that problem.

```
gem "jquery-turbolinks"
```

Comment: Create a gist (and paste link) or another question with your javascript/code. I'll take a look at it and see if I can help.